# Need a web site to perform a user registration and user login

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to do a small hands-on QA session for some students, I'm planning to do a selenium automation test for user registration and login with the same user id and password.
Is there any live website where I can easily register (Without any activation links) and perform a valid login.

Comment: Any website that you own / control you can use. This might be your Wordpress blog, or some specific pages you've built.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [This Websit](https://phptravels.com/demo/)

This link will be helpful [Practice Sites](https://www.techbeamers.com/websites-to-practice-selenium-webdriver-online/)

they provide that sites for demo automation purposes

And also you can get HRM site free for one month with all functionalities (OrangeHRM)